# javascript calculating for math sign of 0 and -0 without ECMA 6, will i run into hell doing this?

Tags: javascript

I simply have this ternary operator. So I can do movements on a grid that has locations of 0 and -0 since -0 + 1 returns 1;

```
-0 + 1 === 1 ? 0 : -0 + 1;
```

Will I run into hell from some unknown javascript thingy seeing as Math.sign() is not even in beta yet? Right now I was just saving the coordinates as strings and requiring the user do the same but that seems stupid.

Comment: ?? do you really have to do that?

Comment: subtract and add to 0 and -0? Yes I do. Use a ternary? No I can build a larger function or alter Oriol's below.

Comment: I don't quite get the logic of that code. Why do you need to check for the sign of zero if it doesn't affect the calculations? Why does the grid have both negative and positive zero locations?

Comment: Because it does by design. Its makes more sense visually for what I am building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know whether you are working with negative zero or positive zero, you can do:

```
function isNegativeZero(v) {
    if (v !== 0) {
        throw Error('Expected "v" to be +-0');
    }
    return Infinity / v === -Infinity;
}
```

Comment: OOH!Did not know of Infinity!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to use [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) on browsers that don't support it, you can polyfill it:

```
function sign(x) {
    x = +x // convert to a number
    if (x === 0 || isNaN(x))
        return x
    return x > 0 ? 1 : -1
}
```

Comment: Hmmm i'll tinker with this one and add -0 check. I "simply" have to see if I added 1 to -0 so I return 0 without skipping 0 since 0 and -0 are places on the grid. Thank you for this i'll tweak it.